# UIImageView cornerradius and CGrect

Tags: ios, uiimageview, geometry, cgrect

I am making a game where you touch a ball and have to pass some bars. However the ball must not touch those bars. The ball is a gif-image. My problem is: The ball is a circle but the uiimageview is a square. If the corners of the uiimageview (which is not the ball image) touch the bars it says that the ball touches the bar. even if I do that

```
// imageMover is the UIImageView
// the radius of the ball is 30.0
[[imageMover layer] setMasksToBounds:YES];
[[imageMover layer] setCornerRadius:30.0f];
```

there is no change. I think i need a rounded frame (CGRect) but how do you "create" a rounded frame?

Comment: How are you actually implementing your collision detection?

Comment: if (CGRectIntersectsRect([bar frame], [imageMover frame]) ) {
// handle stuff
}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22047904/collision-accuracy

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
imageMover.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;

imageMover.clipsToBounds = YES;

imageMover.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f; // what number you want
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot creat a rounded frame.

but you can create an UIImageView with rounded corners.

Import the QuartzCore (#import ) header and play with the layer property of the UIImageView.

```
    imageMover.layer.cornerRadius = yourRadius;
    imageMover.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

see the CALayer class reference for detail:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html

thanks!