# Collision accuracy

Tags: ios, objective-c, collision-detection

Not quite sure how to word this but I've been using

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame, bottom.frame)) {
    [self finish ];
}
```

for my collision detection and it run the code perfectly but the ball sometimes collides with the bottom and runs the code but you can clearly see there is a gap in between the objects. i have created the images my self and they have no background around them. i was wondering if theres any other way of coding it or making it so the  it doesn't run the code until the intersect x amount of pixels into one another.

Comment: Oops -- Xed iOS when I should have Xed Xcode.

Comment: `CGRect intersectRect = CGRectIntersection(ball.frame, bottom.frame);
if (intersectRect.size.width >= yourMinimum && intersectRect.size.height >= yourMinimum){[self finish];}`?

Comment: To the OP:  This has nothing to do with Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement ball-line collision in many ways. Your solution is in fact a rectangle - rectangle collision detection. Here is how I did it in one of my small gaming projects. It gave me best results and it's simple.

Let's say that a ball has a `ballRadius`, and location `(xBall, yBall)`. The line is defined with two points `(xStart, yStart)` and `(xEnd, yEnd)`.

Implementation of a simple collision detection:

```
float ballRadius = ...;
float x1 = xStart - xBall;
float y1 = yStart - yBall;

float x2 = xEnd - xBall;
float y2 = yEnd - yBall;

float dx = x2 - x1;
float dy = y2 - y1;
float dr = sqrtf(powf(dx, 2) + powf(dy, 2));
float D = x1*y2 - x2*y1;

float delta = powf(ballRadius*0.9,2)*powf(dr,2) - powf(D,2);

if (delta >= 0) 
{ 
    // Collision detected 
}
```

If delta is greater than zero there are two intersections between ball (circle) and line. If delta is equal to zero there is one intersection – perfect collision.